# Pretty print xml code and put in a variable

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree, pretty-print

I just found this method on Stackoverflow to print an xml code :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    j = "\n" + (level-1)*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for subelem in elem:
            indent(subelem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = j
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = j
    return elem        

root = ElementTree.parse('/tmp/xmlfile').getroot()
indent(root)
ElementTree.dump(root)
```

But i would like to put what i print in a variable.
I tried the simplest way :

```
data = Elementtree.dump(root)
print("==>", data)
```

But it returns me "==> None"
It's like : ElementTree.dump(root) is printing no matter what.

Thanks for helping

Comment: You are correct that dump always prints. From the docs: `xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(elem)`
Writes an element tree or element structure to sys.stdout. This function should be used for debugging only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = Elementtree.tostring(root)
print("==>", data)
```

Comment: Explanation: `dump()`(which should only be used for debugging) does not return anything, but `tostring()` does. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#functions.

Comment: Thanks ! i just need to make it readable because it returns me the string in one line but it's perfect !